# AuthorizationScope in Springfox

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I try config swagger for my Spring boot application. I use this link for config https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-swagger-jwt. I change some parts

```java
@Bean
public Docket swaggerCustomConfiguration() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiDetails())
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(apiKey()))
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
            .build()
            .protocols(swaggerProtocols)
            .host(swaggerHostUrl);
}

private ApiInfo apiDetails() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(swaggerTitle)
            .description(swaggerDescription)
            .termsOfServiceUrl(termsOfServiceUrl)
            .version("v" + serverVersionCode + "-" + serverVersionName)
            .build();
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    final AuthorizationScope readScope = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read scope");
    final AuthorizationScope writeScope = new AuthorizationScope("write", "write scope");
    return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer",
            new AuthorizationScope[]{readScope, writeScope}));
}
```

But something I don't know is `AuthorizationScope`. I don't know what is doing `AuthorizationScope` exactly. Can Introduce any link to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly the answer to your question, but you can consider moving to springdoc. It is a more recent and in my opinion a much better and easier to work with library. Take a look at it:

- https://springdoc.org/
- https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Springfox has become a pain to use with so many bugs and hard to configure features.